# WooCommerce: Change size of up / down buttons on product quantity area

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to adjust the size of the up/down arrows in the quantity box in WooCommerce, and I am completely stumped!

I want them bigger in height, so they are easier to click.  Any help would be greatly appreciated; this site has helped me tons.

[live example here](http://hysteriamachine.meexis.co.uk/shop/resin-cast-bat-skull-earrings/)

Comment: Those arrows are called spinners and you can style it, see this example http://jsfiddle.net/BnEmn/1/

Comment: hi thanks for that, i just tried styling them in there but didn't seem to change anything?

Comment: I made minor changes to correct spelling and be consistent in capitalization.  An attractive post will gather a qualified Readership more quickly, hopefully leading to better Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar WooCommerce requirement although I wanted to shrink the up/down quantity spinners on anything but mobile. Your site seems to be down but here's what I added to my child themes style.css to override the defaults(*NOTE*: I was using the WooCommerce Composite plugin which MAY have modified the HTML and therefore CSS selectors required)

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .product-info .product-content #product .add-to-cart .cart .quantity{
        width:74px !important;
    }

    .product-info .product-content #product .add-to-cart .cart .quantity input[type="number"]{
        padding:6px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    .product-info .product-content #product .add-to-cart .cart .quantity input[type="button"]{
        line-height:1em !important;
        height:15px !important;
    }

    .product-info .product-content #product .add-to-cart .cart .quantity{
        margin-right:10px !important;
    }
}
```

The main areas of interest are the reduction in line-height and padding. This allowed the up/down spinners to adjust height whilst keeping the +/- symbols vertically centered. I wrapped my modifications within a media query so I could target anything larger than 480px.

I imagine you could do something similar but simply increase line-height and padding to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for an answer, Try to use line-height. Below example is for the quantity field on single product page.

```
.woocommerce.single-product .quantity .qty {
  line-height: 35px;
}
```